# how to change Authorize attribute's parameter at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to change parameters of attribute at run time?
I have a service in which I am assigning roles who can access the service. I want to assign these roles at run time.

```
  [HttpGet]
   [Authorize(Roles="admin")]
    public DataTable GetAllProducts()
    {
        FormToken auth = new FormToken();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        if (!auth.isAuthenticated())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Error");
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Error"] = "Login to get the Service";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            return dt;
        }
        var rec = from log in db.Products select log;
        return rec.ToDataTable();
```

Comment: I know same type of question was asked before but I did not found any satisfactory answer on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vivek,

The authorize attribute can be inherited from and you can override the OnAuthorize method. Something like below.

```
public sealed class AuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //do custom authorization here
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

At this point you can do anything you wish for authorization. You can add custom constructors to set your own variables. For example I currently use this override to detect if the user is authorized and they have access to a specific location.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The method proposed by @Nico will work.

An alternative, that arguably provides better encapsulation and flexibility is to use the `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` instead of the `AuthorizeAttribute`. This is part of WIF, which is in theory the preferred framework for identity and authorization in .Net.

In this model, the `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` specifies the *authorization context* of the request, in terms of an Resource and Operation - that is it describes the request, not who can access it.

The actual authorization logic is then encapsulated in a custom `ClaimAuthorizationManager` that is given the current user principal and the authorization context. It's job is purely to do the authorization check. The `ClaimAuthorizationManager` can be controlled by configuration in the application web.config file.

This is all described here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.claimsprincipalpermissionattribute.aspx

Although I prefer this method I don't think there are *very* strong reasons to prefer one over the other. I think the advantage of this approach are:

- It provides better encapsulation
- It is more flexible
- It is called by the CLR rather than the MVC framework, meaning it will get called by unit tests or anywhere the decorated method is called
- It can be used imperatively as well as declaratively (`ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess("Customer","Add"))`
- It seems to be more aligned with the direction Microsoft are going

A disadvantage is

- It is .Net 4.5 only. If you are on .Net 3.5 or 4, then you would have to use the earlier version of WIF. It is very similar to the .Net 4.5 version (but not identical). The namespaces are `Microsoft.IdentityModel` instead of `System.IdentityModel`

As I say though, it is a mostly a matter of preference in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

For non-declarative user permission verification, you may want to consider using [`System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermission.aspx) instead of `AuthorizeAttribute`.  This would allow you to specify the target role at runtime.  Depending on how you are doing authentication, you may need to ensure that the authenticated user principal is assigned to `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, which is what `PrincipalPermission` uses, as opposed to just `HttpContext.Current.User` (which is what the MVC `AuthorizeAttribute` uses).

Comment: can you give a code example to use this?